# Access the database construct within a class

Tags: php

I have been experimenting with persistent data from a class construct, I am trying to make a persistent connection through my public __construct, so I can use my database connection information throughout my class. My code is as followed:

```
class Inbox {
   # private $Database;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->$Database = new mysqli ('localhost','root','xxx','test');
    }
    public static function TestConnect (){
        if (self::Database){
            echo "Success When Connecting To Database";
        }else{
            echo "Problems When Connecting To Database";
        }
    }
    public static function TestSelect(){
        $Select = $this->Database->prepare("SELECT * FROM test");
        $Select->execute();
        $Select->bind_result($Test_ID, $Test_UName);
        $Select->fetch();

        print_r($Select);
    }
}

$Foo = new Inbox();
$Foo->TestSelect();
```

Now. When running

I am presented with the following errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: Database in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\InboxFeature\Api\Class.php on line 15
>
> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\InboxFeature\Api\Class.php on line 15

---

I change my lines to:

```
$Select = self::Database->prepare("SELECT * FROM test");
```

and uncomment:
    `private $Database;`

I get presented with the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\InboxFeature\Api\Class.php on line 25

So my overall question, is where exactly have I gone wrong, I have looked at examples shown on Stackoverflow with using the `__construct()` method. I can't see where it's gone wrong for me.

---

**Using the Answer provided. I appended the following changes:**

```
 private static $Database;
    public function __construct() {
        self::$Database = new mysqli ('localhost','root','xxx','test');
    }
    public static function TestSelect(){
        $Select = self::$Database->prepare("SELECT * FROM test");
        $Select->execute();
        $Select->bind_result($Test_ID, $Test_UName);
        $Select->fetch();

        echo $Test_ID;
    }
```

This has successfully worked. Thank you  for the quick response

Comment: declare $Database variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the syntax reversed.

If you declare the property as `private $database;` then you would access it using `$this->database`, not `$this->$database`.

If you instead declare it as a static property (`private static $database`) then it would be `self::$database`, not `self::database`.

Either way, you should make sure the property is declared at the top of the class; in your example you have `private $database` commented out.

Comment: Was commented out because I was trying all different methods. I have it working now. My Question updates will show what i've done. I will accept the answer when I can, due to the time limit

Comment: Whoever downvoted my answer - why?

Comment: I've still got mine set to +1 so it wasnt me